# Users are getting access denied message when group they are in has access?

Tags: access-denied

Hello
We have a document library that a group of users is given Read access to.  Checking the effective permissions on a member of the group confirms this.  We also have 2 documents that inherit the parent permissions (both .mht files).  Sending a link to the sharepoint document via email users can access one document but not the other.  Checking effective permissions confirms they have access to one but not the other even though both are inheriting from the parent and neither have any custom permissions.

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the site in which this document library is situated has given no access to the group for whom is getting the access denied message?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the solution, Dan, but I wonder if the .mht's are similar in nature or not.  Does the one that doesn't work, perhaps, reference another artifact on the portal to which the users do not have permission?

Comment: no, it doesnt reference anything outside of whats already in the file. both mhtml files display almost the same thing (just a monthly update).  ive tried uploading other files (like a css file) but it still doesnt work.  viewing the permissions for both they look exactly the same but only checking the effective permissions shows up the problem